# How to solve the integral $\int_0^\pi\ln(\sin(\theta))\sin(\theta)d\theta$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, mathematical-physics

Could you help me with a comprehensive one?  I have tried to solve it but I can't reach the result. The integral I am trying to evaluate is
$$\int_0^\pi\ln(\sin(\theta))\sin(\theta)d\theta$$and according to Wolfram alpha the result should be $\ln(4)-2$.

I already have tried to evaluate it using integration by parts but, when doing so, I find a term of $\cos(\theta)\ln(\sin(\theta)) $ which is evaluated from $0$ to $\pi$ and this is where I stay because those values make the result ​​indeterminate. I have tried to make variable changes but I have not been able to find a suitable one that allows me to avoid indeterminate results. I would like you to provide me with a suggestion to avoid the indeterminacies.

Comment: Sorry to rollback your most recent edit, but it's a very good idea to make your title as informative as possible. It's best to leave the integral written out in the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:
\begin{align*}&\ \ \ \ \int_0^\pi\ln(\sin(\theta))\sin(\theta)d\theta \\&= 
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi\ln(1-\cos^2(\theta))\sin(\theta) d\theta= \\ &=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^\pi\ln(1-\cos(\theta))d(1-\cos(\theta))-\int_0^\pi\ln(1+\cos(\theta))d(1+\cos(\theta))\right) \\ &=\frac{1}{2}\left((1-\cos(\theta))(\ln(1-\cos(\theta))-1)|_{0}^{\pi}-(1+\cos(\theta))(\ln(1+\cos(\theta))-1)|_{0}^{\pi}\right) \\ &=\frac{1}{2}(2\ln 2-2+2\ln 2 -2)\\&= \ln(4)-2
\end{align*}

Comment: Beat me to it +1.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  She hadn't seen it that way.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^\pi  \ln (\sin \theta) \sin \theta d \theta  &=2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (\sin \theta) \sin \theta d \theta \\
= & -2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (\sin \theta) d(\cos \theta-1) \quad \textrm{ (IBP)} \\
= &  \underbrace{ -2[(\cos \theta-1) \ln (\sin \theta)]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}}_{=0} +2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos \theta-1}{\sin \theta} \cdot \cos \theta d \theta\\=& 2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \frac{\cos \theta-1}{\sin \theta} d(\sin \theta)\\=& 2[\cos \theta-1] _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-2\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos \theta-1}{\sin \theta} d \theta\\=&-2 +2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \tan \frac{\theta}{2} d \theta\\=&-2 -4\left[\ln \left(\cos \frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\\=&2(\ln2-1)
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 2):

This integral is related to the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Other_identities_and_formulas). Substitute $\theta=\tau+\dfrac\pi2$ and take advantage of symmetry to write

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^\pi \ln(\sin \theta) \sin \theta \, d\theta \\
&= \int_{-\tfrac\pi2}^{\tfrac\pi2} \ln\left(\sin \left(\tau+\frac\pi2\right)\right) \sin \left(\tau+\frac\pi2\right) \, d\tau \\
&= \int_{-\tfrac\pi2}^{\tfrac\pi2} \ln(\cos \tau) \cos \tau \, d\tau \\
&= 2 \int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \ln(\cos \tau) \cos \tau \, d\tau \\
&= 2 \lim_{a\to1} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \cos^a\tau \, d\tau \\
&= \lim_{a\to1} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \operatorname{B}\left(\frac12,\frac a2+\frac12\right) \\
&= \frac12 \lim_{a\to1} \operatorname{B}\left(\frac12,\frac a2+\frac12\right) \left[\psi\left(\frac a2+\frac12\right)- \psi\left(\frac a2+1\right)\right] \\
&= -\gamma - (-\gamma+2-\ln4)
\end{align*}$$

and the result follows. $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\psi$ denotes [digamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Comment: It's a pretty interesting solution. But, I don't understand how you went from the first line to the second. It's not clear to me how you found the new limits.

Comment: @Kale_1729 I've updated my answer to clarify

Comment: It is perfectly clear.  No doubt.  Thank you very much for clarifying my idea more.  I really like this solution.  It's quite original.

Comment: I just want to comment on something if I'm right.  You separate the integral from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ into two integrals, one that goes from $-\pi/2$ to $0$ and another that goes from $0$ to $\pi/2 $.  However, due to cosine parity, both integrals are equal, that is, evaluating from $-\pi/2$ to $0$ is the same as evaluating from $0$ to $\pi/2$, is this correct?

Comment: Precisely. It's the same as saying the original integrand with $\sin$ is symmetric about $\theta=\frac\pi2$.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much, your proposed solution was quite clear to me. Very good.

Comment: I have one more doubt. When we calculate the partial derivative of the beta function, why does the term 1/2 appear?

Comment: It comes from differentiating the $\frac a2$ term (chain rule)

Comment: I understand. The thing is, I looked at the link you posted about the beta function and it shows what the partial derivative of the beta function is like, but it doesn't show that the beta arguments must be derived. For that reason I didn't understand that part

Comment: I assume you're referring to the supposedly untouched factor of $\operatorname{B}(a,b)$ in the first expression in [Derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Derivatives)? Write beta in terms of gamma, differentiate, and simplify. The beta term then comes back after writing in terms of digamma.